# PHP INCLUDE: syntax error, unexpected T_INCLUDE, expecting T_CASE or T_DEFAULT or '}'

Tags: php

I'm trying to change this:

```
switch ($lang){

        case "es":
            include("index_es.php");
            break;
        case "en":
            include("index_en.php");
            break;
        default:
            include("index_en.php");
            break;
    }
```

to this:

```
switch ($lang){
            include("languages.php");   
    }
```

in the languages file is where ill have all the `case`, `include`, and `break` information.  Whats wrong with the code that it causes a syntax error?

Comment: Why do you even need a `switch` at all? Just put your `include` and be done

Comment: Must be you can't `include` the `case` statements.

Comment: @Machavity im trying to change the language based no the browsers language

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara is there another way to do what im trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an `include` to replace the `case` statements of a `switch`.

Instead, put the entire thing, `switch {}` and all, within the include file.

That said, a better solution, especially if you add more languages, might be:

```
if(in_array($lang, ['es', 'fr', '...'])) {
    include('index_' . $lang . '.php');
} else {
    include('index_en.php');
}
```

Comment: how does this work? this looks interesting and will this work with all the browser codes seen here: http://www.metamodpro.com/browser-language-codes ?

Comment: @JoeBobby Why wouldn't it? How it works should be pretty clear.

Comment: i dont understand arrays too much, but from what it looks like it will check for index_es.php, index_fr.php, etc and if those arent found in the folder it will display index_en.php?

Comment: @JoeBobby Right. By using `in_array`, it will only handle languages you've explicitly told it to, and fall back to English as the default. This protects you from users trying to put in invalid language values to break/exploit your app.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```php
$lang_file = 'index_' . $lang . '.php';
include_once( $lang_file );
```

Comment: This is potentially dangerous if `$lang` comes from user input.

Comment: Yes, I know, he will need to validate it before, maybe make a function that will sanitize the input, and include the required file.